# Accessing directly a Sql Server Database in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm just a beginner in using Xamarin. I created a sample Xamarin.Forms Portable project in Visual Studio 2013. I want to know if it is possible to access an MS SQL database and display it to my mobile phone? If Yes, can you please give me some instruction on how am I going to do this? Thanks a lot. I hope someone will help me.

Comment: Yes you [can](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection/)

Comment: @Martheen thanks for the answer. Can you please give me instructions on how will I do this?

Comment: That's not what stackoverflow for. The link I've given contain enough instruction. Try them first, write the codes, then ask if you found a problem.

Comment: @Martheen where's the link you're talking about?

Comment: The 'can' word is clickable

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot access directly an sql server from your pcl project in Xamarin.Forms because `System.Data.SqlClient` is not available on pcl.

But you can do it through a **dependency service**.

First in you PCL project declare you service

```
public interface IDbDataFetcher
    {
        string GetData(string conn);
    }
```

Then on you Android project implement the service interface

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(DbFetcher))]
namespace App.Droid.Services
{
    class DbFetcher : IDbDataFetcher
    {

        public List<string> GetData(string conn)
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conn))
            {

                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select * from smuser", connection);
                try
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        data.Add(reader[0].ToString());
                    }
                    reader.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
            }
            return data;
        }
    }
}
```

Although it is a solution it is a **bad** one. Always consume web services for your mobile apps

Comment: Thanks for the answer Sir. I have created a sample project and tried using REST web service API that I've watched in a tutorial. And have it checked with some other resource. They said that I do not have error in code but maybe in binding. Since I'm just a newbie in using Xamarin, I wasn't able to find out what's the cause of my problem. Can you check it anyway? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Jaycee, Could you give your tutorial's address?

Comment: @JayceeEvangelista, Is this code  established connection and fetch data?