# Can't use System.Data.SqlClient on Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I need to use `System.Data.SqlClient` on an app I'm developing with Xamarin.Forms but I'm not able to use this package. I tried adding it to the ".Droid" project (it seems it is not available on PCL) but it's not found in the namespace. I added it through the NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio 2015.

I need to do something like [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37876772/2418824). I know it's not recommended. I plan to develop a REST API later on, but for now I need to do this way in order to build a prototype/alpha version of the app.

EDIT: If I can't use SqlClient, what can I use in Xamarin to open a connection with a SQL Server?

Comment: I had the same issue using Xamarin a while back. To my knowledge SQLite is what is supported. What I did get to work however was Azure SQL with Xamarin, which works really well and I think you should be able to use SQL Server Management Studio with it. I don't think there is actually a question being asked in your OP tho, so my comment is sort of a thought from reading your post.

Comment: You can include references to System.Data and Mono.Data.Tds in your Mono projects like iOS and connect directly to MSSQL. However, doing so means you have to enable TCP/IP on the MSSQL Server to allow the iOS or Android device to connect directly to MSSQL, which imposes potential security risks. It's better to put the data behind an authenticated ASP.NET Core JSON API and then consume through Xamarin.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `System.Data.SqlClient` you will be required to use the approach as mentioned in the post you linked to yourself. The simple reason being that the package is not built as a PCL.

If that's not viable, the use the [`SQLite.NET` package](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/data/part_3_using_sqlite_orm/) which is PCL compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Download `system.data.sqlite` package from `NuGet` in your app. It will provides you assemblies like `system.data`, `system.data.sqlclient` and `system.data.sqlLite` and much more for database connections.

Answer (score -1):

SQLite is the recommended way for implementing a SQL Database to a Xamarin.Forms app.

Here is a walkthrough to add SQLite to your Xamarin.Forms application!

## Walkthrough

#### 1. Add SQLite NuGet Package

Add the [SQLite-net NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net-pcl) created by [@Frank Krueger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/338/frank-krueger) into each Project in your Solution; i.e. add this NuGet package to your Xamarin.Forms PCL, Android project, etc.

#### 2. Create Database Class

Add this class to your Xamarin.Forms PCL.

This Database class will be used to save data to, and load data from your SQLite Database.

```
public class Database
{
    #region Constant Fields
    readonly static object _locker = new object();
    readonly SQLiteConnection _database;
    #endregion

    #region Constructors
    public Database()
    {
        _database = DependencyService.Get<ISQLite>().GetConnection();
        _database.CreateTable<DataModel>();
    }
    #endregion

    #region Methods
    public async Task<IList<DataModel>> GetAllDataAsync()
    {
        return await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            lock (_locker)
            {
                return _database.Table<DataModel>().ToList();
            }
        });
    }

    public async Task<int> SaveDataAsync(DataModel dataModel)
    {
        var isDataInDatabase = (await GetAllDataAsync()).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Equals(dataModel)) != null;

        return await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            if (isDataInDatabase)
            {
                lock (_locker)
                {
                    _database.Update(dataModel);
                }
                return dataModel.ID;
            }

            lock (_locker)
            {
                return _database.Insert(dataModel);
            }
        });
    }
    #endregion
```

#### 3. Create ISQLite Interface

Add this interface to your Xamarin.Forms PCL.

This interface will allow you to use the Dependancy Service to retrieve the database connection using the platform-specific API

```
public interface ISQLite
{
    SQLiteConnection GetConnection();
}
```

#### 4. Create iOS Implementation of ISQLite

Add this class to your Android PCL

This Implementation of the ISQLite database will retrieve the database connection using the Xamarin.Android Folder Path.

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(SQLite_Android))]
namespace SampleApp.Droid
{
    public class SQLite_Android : ISQLite
    {
        #region ISQLite implementation
        public SQLiteConnection GetConnection()
        {
            var sqliteFilename = "SQLiteDatabase.db3";
            string documentsPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal); // Documents folder
            var path = Path.Combine(documentsPath, sqliteFilename);

            var conn = new SQLiteConnection(path, SQLiteOpenFlags.ReadWrite | SQLiteOpenFlags.Create | SQLiteOpenFlags.SharedCache);

            // Return the database connection 
            return conn;
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

#### 5. In App.cs, Add a Static Implementation to the Database

Add this static implementation of `Database.cs` into the `App` class of your Xamarin.Forms PCL.

```
public class App : Application
{
    static OpportunityModelDatabase _database;

    ...

    public static OpportunityModelDatabase Database =>
        _database ?? (_database = new OpportunityModelDatabase());
}
```

#### 6. Now Access the Database Data from Anywhere in Your App

Here is an example of how to retrieve the data from a different class

```
var AllData = await App.Database.GetAllDataAsync();
```

## Sample App

Here is a sample app I've created that demonstrates how to implement SQLite in a Xamarin.Forms app. Feel free to download it to get a better understanding of how to implement SQLite!
https://github.com/brminnick/InvestmentDataSampleApp

Comment: I don't want to implement a local database. I want my app to connect to a remote database, stored on a SQL Server.

Comment: @jorgemoreira is your data hosted on Azure?

Comment: Then you need to write your front-end (GUI/Mobile Phone whatever) totally independent from your SQL Database and the use Http calls (not SQL connects) to a non-GUI back-end which services the Http request, does the SQL and returns the data.  Its the only way through this swamp of a development 'system' ....