# Getting GPS Coordinates from db for every row and pin pointing them on map

Tags: c#, sql, google-maps, xamarin, gps

**EDIT:**
I have read [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37873020/accessing-directly-a-sql-server-database-in-xamarin-forms) on how to do what I am required so I have added the DbFetcher code to the MainActvity.cs in the Android project

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;

using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;
using Android.Content.PM;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(DbFetcher))]
namespace WorkingWithMaps.Android
{

[Activity(Label = "WorkingWithMaps.Android.Android", Icon = "@drawable/icon", MainLauncher = true,
    ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
public class MainActivity :
global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity // superclass new in 1.3
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
        global::Xamarin.FormsMaps.Init(this, bundle);

        LoadApplication(new App()); // method is new in 1.3
    }
}

    class DbFetcher : IDbDataFetcher
    {

        public List<string> GetData(string conn)
        {
        conn = @"Server=<sql8.freemysqlhosting.net>;Database=<sql8159905>;User Id=<sql8159905>;Password=<FpqWnwwpjs>;Trusted_Connection=true";

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conn))
            {

                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select Name, Latitude, Longitude from tblTest", connection);
                try
                {
                connection.Open();
                using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    var list = new List<PinPage>();
                    while (reader.Read())
                    list.Add(new PinPage {Col0 = reader.GetInt(0), Col1 = reader.GetString(1), Col2 = reader.GetDouble(2), Col3 = reader.getDouble(3)});
                    allRecords = list.ToArray();
                }
                reader.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
            }
            return allRecords;
        }
    }
}
```

And also in my PCL project I have changed my code up from the original code posted here to implement the DbFetcher stuff from the Android Project.

The issue that I am having is getting the foreach method to call up the array "allRecords" from the main activity in the android project.

What I need the foreach to do is get all of Col0 (ID) and for each of those it must return, Col1(Name),, Col2(Lat), Col3(Long) but I am unable to get the foreach to call use the array from the android project.

How do I get this to work?

```
using Plugin.Geolocator;
using SQLite;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Maps;
using XamarinForms.SQLite;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using Android.App;

namespace WorkingWithMaps  
{
public class PinPage : ContentPage 
{
    int Col0 { get; set; }
    string Col1 { get; set; }
    double Col2 { get; set; }
    double Col3 { get; set; }

    Map map;

    public PinPage()
    {
        map = new Map {
            IsShowingUser = true,
            HeightRequest = 100,
            WidthRequest = 960,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
        };


    }

    public interface IDbDataFetcher
    {
        string GetData(string connection);




    }
    protected async override void OnAppearing()
    {

            // create pins

            base.OnAppearing();
            var morePins = new Button { Text = "Show Tests Near Me" };

        //create con to db





        //current pos
        var locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;
            locator.DesiredAccuracy = 50;


            var position = await locator.GetPositionAsync(timeoutMilliseconds: 10000);
            var reLocate = new Button { Text = "Re-center" };
            reLocate.Clicked += (sender, e) => {
            map.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(
            new Position(position.Latitude, position.Longitude), Distance.FromMiles(0.5)));


            };


            var buttons = new StackLayout
            {
                Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
                Children = {
                morePins, reLocate
            }
            };




        foreach(int Col0 in allRecords)
        {
            morePins.Clicked += (sender, e) =>
            {
                map.Pins.Add(new Pin
                {
                    Position = new Position(Col2, Col3),
                    Label = Col1

                });

            };


            //map.Pins.Add(new Pin {
            //  Position = new Position(-26.080752, 28.026094),
            //  Label = "Mercedes-Benz - Bryanston"
//            });
//            map.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(
//            new Position(position.Latitude, position.Longitude), Distance.FromMiles(2))); // this distance shows dealerships to current position

//            };


        // put the page together
        Content = new StackLayout { 
            Spacing = 0,
            Children = {
                map,
                buttons
            }};

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [*Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b571cd42-c92f-4a2c-95de-4ddf9b24aa3b/what-does-this-error-message-mean?forum=lightswitch)

Comment: what *specifically* are you having problems with?  Connecting to the db?  Executing the query?  Plotting the points on the map?  Generally, connecting directly to a remote db is a bad idea.  Instead you would typically expose your db via a webservice.

Comment: Connecting to the db in the portable class, and then I need to get Name, Lat and Long to come from the db for each ID and create pins all over if they are within a certain distance from me, its set to within 2 miles right now. I need help with everything mentioned above. I understand that connecting to a remote db is a bad idea but I would like to try to get this to work. The table is just going to have random locations with "ID, Name, Lat, Long" which is not a security issue for me as those are just test values for now.

Comment: Please have a look at this part of the code " morePins.Clicked += (sender, e) => {
    map.Pins.Add(new Pin {
        Position = new Position(-26.074932, 28.012136),
        Label = "Test 1"  "  - this works well because it is hard coded, what I need is for the lat and long coordinates, as well as the Name, to come from my db . Not sure how to do the array to make it get everything that I need. Also, the sql connection is giving me issues in this portable class.

Comment: @Jason please have a look from "EDIT" in my original post. I have made a few changes so please have a look to see if you can help me sort out the new problem regarding the foreach method