# Xamarin forms and sql server Database

Tags: c#, sql-server, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I was working on UWP project in visual studio #xamarin forms, how do i connect to sql Database without using any Web API's and dependency services ?
The application is working in offline mode.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing directly a Sql Server Database in Xamarin.Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37873020/accessing-directly-a-sql-server-database-in-xamarin-forms)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I have seen this post earlier. My concern is how to access without using any dependency services and API, as my application is going to be in offline mode.

Comment: you mean a local database in you UWP (like SQLite) or a SQL database installed on your computer?

Comment: yes exactly. @Hugo

Comment: @krishnaP exactly what?

Comment: what i mean is a local database like SQLite or SQL databaseinstalled on my computer. @hugo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you must decide whether you want to use Microsoft SQL Server or Sqlite.
These are completely different databases and therefore the code will be different as well.

If you want to use MS SQL, you can use [this article](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/How-to-access-data-from-935e360c).

Somehow from your questions I think that Sqlite will serve you better (just my guess).

If you want to use Sqlite, check [this one](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/databases/).
This recipe is designed for Xamarin.Forms **PCL** project and therefore uses dependency service - since the approach is different on iOS, Android and UWP. If you do not plan to port your project to Android or iOS, you can just call the functions directly, without dependcy service interface.

Comment: Thanks for the Solution.

Comment: You are welcome. You can accept the answer, so that other people will know that it's ok.